# How do you decrypt EncryptedSharedPreferences on a rooted emulator

Tags: root-access, security, encryption

I'm trying to put together a PoC to show that a root user can decrypt any app data that relies on the keystore.

On a rooted emulator, I installed an app that uses *EncryptedSharedPreferences*.
I can see that the related key in stored in */data/misc/keystore/user_0* (There are USRPKEY and USRCERT files in binary format that belong to the app).

What are the next steps to actually decrypt the EncryptedSharedPreferences xml files?
A series of shell commands to run would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: EncryptedSharedPreferences from androidx.security uses the hardware backed AndroidKeyStore, so key extraction should not be possible, only key usage should be possible with root permissions. So I would assume the most easiest way to decrypt the shared preference is to write some Java code that requests the key from keystore and does the decryption. Then compile the code to class and dex code so that you can execute it on command-line as the user-id the app is installed to.